# What's the difference between maven-rpm-plugin and rpm-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, rpm, rpm-maven-plugin

I see references to both on line but can't find out why. Is there a difference? If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

maven-rpm-plugin is an older version of the plugin (which I suspect works with maven-1). [rpm-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/) is the one which works with the current versions of maven.  You should be using this.